# Blocking touches in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, touch, block

Is there a way to totally block touches in cocos2d (assume, file or something is loading and I don't want user to be able press anything) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ignore all interactions:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

to unignore use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Answer (score 2):

Manually you need to remove touches for menu and layer.

//Cocos2d 2.0

```
menu.touchEnabled = NO;   
layer.touchEnabled = NO;
```

//Cocos2d 1.0

```
menu.isTouchEnabled = NO;
```